# How to pass an access code from gmail api to a node worker in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-api, gmail, discord.js

### The Application

I have written a discord bot with *discord.js* as a simple *node.js* application, not a webserver. I have integrated the gmail api with a credentials file to authenticate myself to access emails. This works perfectly in development on localhost.

### The Problem

When I start up the app, google prompts me to go to an external url and authorize the app. There I get a code and in the console of my application I am prompted to enter that code. It is fine when I run it on my machine, but when running on heroku, I just can't seem to pass the code back to the application.

### My (failed) Solutions

I have tried so far:

- to use the *heroku cli* to pass the code back
- to use the integrated console (dynamo) in the *heroku* interface to pass the code back
- to blindly copy it in the logs when I was really desperate

In all attempts, the token was not saved in my deployed application, so the prompt came again and again.

### The Code

The code in question to pass the code back is this:

```
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: SCOPES,
  });

  console.log("Authorize this app by visiting this url:", authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });

  rl.question("Enter the code from that page here: ", code => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error("Error retrieving access token", err);
      }
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      Fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), err => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log("Token stored to", TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}
```

What can I do to solve this? Maybe just log the token via `console` and save it manually? Or is there another simpler way to authenticate that I do not see?

Answer (score 0):

### The Solution

My solution is to exchange the *readline* function for an action from the discord bot and manually trigger the authentification:

```
const { manualAuthorization, sendToken } = require("../authorize-google");

module.exports = {
  name: "authorize-google",
  admin: true,
  execute: async (_message, [code]) => {
    try {
      if (!code) {
        await manualAuthorization();
      } else {
        await sendToken(code);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error.message);
    }
  },
};
```

The first command triggers the authentication and the second one sends the code to the bot:

```
function manualAuthorization() {
  OWNER = client.users.cache.get("someID");

  // Load client secrets from a local file.
  Fs.readFile("google-credentials.json", (err, content) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log("Error loading client secret file:", err);
    }
    // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Gmail API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content));
  });
}

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 */
function authorize(credentials) {
  const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    redirect_uris[0]
  );

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  Fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) {
      return getNewToken(oAuth2Client);
    }
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    OWNER.send("Successfully authorized");
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 */
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: SCOPES,
  });

  client.oAuth2Client = oAuth2Client;

  OWNER.send(`Authorize this app by visiting this url: ${authUrl}`);
}

function sendToken(code) {
  client.oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error("Error retrieving access token", err);
    }

    client.oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
    // Store the token to disk for later program executions
    Fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), err => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
      }
      console.log("Token stored to", TOKEN_PATH);
    });

    OWNER.send("Successfully authorized");
  });
}
```